# Live Activities / Dynamic island can't display images from Asset or Data

Tags: swift, flutter, swiftui, widget, dynamic-island

I can't achieve to display images **from asset** in live activities & dynamic island widgets.

It's work very well with icon but not with image from asset or from UIImage (via Data).

This works:

```swift
Image(systemName: "timer")
```

This **NOT** work:

```swift
Image("pizza")
```

My App asset looks like:

[image: Xcode Asset]

I copied asset in the extension:

[image: Build phase]

The live activity notification is not created when I add the Image from asset. Any help would be appreciated!

What I tried & not working:

- Move asset from main app to extension
- Load image from Data
- Specify fixed sized of the image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue, Image need to be in a small resolution to be displayed in your live activity/dynamic island.

Data must be lower or equal than 4kb, here is the official [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities):

> The updated dynamic data for both ActivityKit updates and ActivityKit push notifications can’t exceed 4KB in size.